# LINQ to XML , retrieving data

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I have this XML:

```
<root>
      <data name="lnkViewResultResource1.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>bekijk de resultaten</value>
  </data>
  <data name="lnkVoteResource1.Text" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>stem</value>
  </data>
  <data name="number of results" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>er waren reeds {0} stemmen op deze poll {1}</value>
  </data>
</root>
```

I want to retrieve the "data" values, and for this I used:

```
Public Shared Function getlabels(ByVal filename As String) As Array
    Dim labels = From l In XElement.Load(filename).Descendants("root").Elements("data") Select l
    Return labels.ToArray
```

But, unfortunately, it is not working, it is not getting anything. 
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Alf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading the `<root>` `XElement` and asking it for *descendants* called `root`. Just get rid of the `Descendants("root")` call and it should be okay.

On the other hand, the query expression is pretty pointless... just use:

```
Return XElement.Load(filename).Elements("data").ToArray
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Dim labels = From l In XElement.Load(filename).Descendants("data") Select l
```